# Replace NVD3 chart with different chart type

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, nvd3.js

I'm trying to replace a discreteBarChart with a pieChart (NVD3 models).
Is there a way to clean/update the chart or element content?

Html code:

```
<div id="chart">
    <svg></svg>
```

Chart initialization:

```
    nv.addGraph(function() {
    var xKey = 'label';
    var yKey = 'value';

    var chart = nv.models.discreteBarChart().x(function(d) {
        return d[xKey]
    }).y(function(d) {
        return d[yKey]
    }).staggerLabels(true)

    .tooltips(false).showValues(true).transitionDuration(250);

    d3.select('#chart svg').datum(defaultData()).call(chart);

    nv.utils.windowResize(chart.update);

    return chart;
});
```

And my atempt to replace the existing chart:

```
function updateToPie(key1, key2) {
    var width = 500,
    height = 500;

    chart = nv.models.pieChart().x(function(d) {
        return d[key1]
    }).y(function(d) {
        return d[key2]
    }).color(d3.scale.category10().range()).width(width).height(height);

    d3.select("#chart svg").datum(chartData[0].values).transition()
            .duration(1200).attr('width', width).attr('height', height)
            .call(chart);

    chart.dispatch.on('stateChange', function(e) {
        nv.log('New State:', JSON.stringify(e));
    });

    return chart;

}
```

However this only overlaps the piechart to the existing barchart. Any help would be apreciated. Thanks

Comment: You could try something like `d3.selectAll("#chart svg > *").remove();`.

Comment: Cool, I'll add that as an answer for reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can remove everything that's there by running

```
d3.selectAll("#chart svg > *").remove();
```

before adding the new chart.